# RFID emulation via NFC

Tags: nfc, access-control, rfid, mifare, applepay

There is an access control system in my university. It uses MIFARE 1k cards.
As I bought Apple Watch with NFC inside, I'm wondering if I can emulate 1k card using NFC.

There is a possibility to send 64KB by NFC using Apple Wallet. But how to order the data from card properly, to send it? The question came because I know that RFID cards has some blocks of data, and unfortunately I don't know how to send them as one unit.

Comment: "RFID" refers to a wide variety of different standards and schemes, can you be more specific? Also, to my knowledge, the NFC hardware in the Apple Watch or Apple iPhone is not exposed to third-party application developers.

Comment: well, i heard about it as well, but you still can create card for Apple Wallet, where in pass.json file there is a tag nfc with message [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/LowerLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH3-SW5). But I see now that I was not right - it is only 64 bytes, not kilobytes